# dynamic view not consistent in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Company company = new Company("XXX");

            ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(company.Departments, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.CompanyName = company.CompanyName;

            return View();
        }
```

This is the view:

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", (string)ViewBag.CompanyName)
<br />
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", "Select Department")
```

I know "Departments" is the dynamic code which belongs to ViewBag.Departments, but why there is no dynamic code in TextBox as it still use ViewBag.CompanyName rathern than just use "CompanyName"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: when you use DropDownList html helper, it checks in view bags if there is a collection with the same name as you provided for the element and tries to generate option list out of it

Answer (score 0):

for `HtmlHelper @Html.DropDownList(...)`

MVC checks if the view bag dictionary already has a collection with the same name what we enter for the drop down list element. If we have not specified select item list with the helper, it tries to generate option list with the collection it finds in view bag dictionary. If you want to override that behavior you can specify your own list like following

using view bag data

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", ViewBag.MyOptionList as SelectList)
```